# When do I need to Kinesis Data Streams together with Kinesis Firehose?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I want to build a use case where I want to do real time analytics. I am not sure when it is necessary to use Kinesis Data Streams before Kinesis Firehose. In the documentation it says that Kinesis Firehose can get the data from Kinesis Data Streams but the use cases are not clear. 
https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/faqs/?nc=sn&loc=5

Answer (score 1):

So the benefit of using Kinesis Firehose to have data passed from Kinesis Data Streams is that it integrates directly with the following services: `S3`, `Redshift`, `ElasticSearch Service`, `Splunk`.

If you want your streamed data to be delivered to any of those endpoints by passing to Firehose you can have it do the work for you.

Traditionally you'd write your own consumer which would be another piece of code to develop and maintain if it breaks. But using Firehose you can rely on AWS to do this part for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mokugo-devops, but then what is the need of Kinesis Data Streams?  I understand that you can already directly connect Kinesis Data Firehose with S3, Redshift, ElasticSearch Service

Comment: Kinesis Data Streams can connect to other sources like Lambda, it is not uncommon with streams to have **multiple** consumers. An event might be stored in S3 (via Firehose), have a Lambda function analyse it and be passed to Data Analytics to be used in analysis of a specific time period. Its nice to have 1 producer in the code, but many consumers